# Load page then launch bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I'm working on a function that works like so:

1. Click Link
2. After page loads based on the link clicked a specific modal window will be displayed
3. Proceed with modal
4. End of functions

My problem I have been running into is that either the modal won't load, or it will load but then close immediately after the page loads. Here is the function I'm working with

```
$(function(){
    $('#new-po').click(function(){
        window.location.href= $(this).attr('href');
        bootbox.dialog({
            title: "Create New Purchase Order",
            message: '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-12">'+
            '<form action="" method="post" id="create-po-form">'+
            '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<div class="col-md-12">'+
            '<div class="form-group row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-6">'+
            '<label>Invoice Number</label>'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inv_num"/>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-6">'+
            '<label>Vendor</label>'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="vendor"/>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-12">'+
            '<div class="form-group row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-6">'+
            '<label>Invoice Number</label>'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="total"/>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-6">'+
            '<label>Vendor</label>'+
            '<select class="form-control" id="status">'+
            '<option value="" selected> -Status-</option>'+
            '<option value="Open">Open</option>'+
            '<option value="Closed">Closed</option>'+
            '<option value="Void">Void</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>',
            buttons:{
                success:{
                    label: "Create PO",
                    className: 'btn-success',
                    callback:function(){


                    }
                }
            },
            onEscape: function(){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

It uses the bootbox extension, and so far I've found no conflict with it, so I'm going to continue using it until otherwise stated. I've tried using `$(document).ready()`, `$(window).load()`, `$(function(){}`, and several other things and nothing has worked. Thoughts?

Also for references my page structure on every page looks like this:

```
<!-- The header contains the html starting tags and the head section -->
<? include "/inc/header/overall_header.php"; ?>
    <!-- html content here -->
<!-- The footer contains the scripts for the pages and the html ending tag -->
<? include "/inc/header/overall_header.php"; ?>
```

Comment: You should move `window.location.href= $(this).attr('href');` this to the success handler of the dialog

Comment: holy crap if I monday'd this function I'm going to kick myself

Comment: OK cool I have added it as an answer

Comment: @MarkHill Do you want the model dialog in newly loaded page or Before loading new page ?

Comment: in the newly loaded page, so upon completion of loading

Answer (score 0):

You should move `window.location.href= $(this).attr('href');` this to the success handler of the dialog

Comment: tried that. It pops up before the window loads then closes immediately. It's almost as if the success callback is firing by default

Comment: I think the success handler should be as in this example "Custom dialog" http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html. It needs another callback

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm thinking no

Answer (score 0):

Once the page is refreshed the javascript is stopped and a new script is loaded.

You should activate the bootbox code in the new page when it is loaded.

For example:

Page #1:

```
$(function(){
    $('#new-po').click(function(){
        window.location.href= $(this).attr('href');   // point to page#2
        // at this point you can't show bootbox or modify the page!
        //  - the browser will simply refresh the page to a new url and your changes will not be shown
    });
}
```

Page #2:

```
$(function(){
    // show bootbox ...
})
```

There are other options achieving what you want -  using iframe to load the page in a frame,  or (much better) loading html with ajax and showing it.

Comment: my javascript is in an include file that contains the same footer for all pages

Comment: that is fine, but activate it when the new page is loaded, not when link is clicked in the old page.  Updated my answer to highlight this point.

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: I edited my question above to show what the structure of my page generally looks like